# How to charge a user using Stripe Connect

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to implement Stripe connect and I got the code working till getting the following response from Stripe

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "stripe_publishable_key": PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
  "scope": "read_write",
  "livemode": false,
  "stripe_user_id": USER_ID,
  "refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
  "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
}
```

This is what my code looks like which gives me the above response.

```
        define('TOKEN_URI', 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token');
        define('AUTHORIZE_URI', 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize');
        define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'xxx');
        define('CLIENT_ID', 'yyy');

        $token_request_body = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
        'code' => $code,
        'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET
    );

    $req = curl_init(TOKEN_URI);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($token_request_body));

    // TODO: Additional error handling
    $respCode = curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $resp = json_decode(curl_exec($req), true);
    curl_close($req);
```

I am assuming that since I am not asking for the credit card number from the user so the amount will be deducted from the user bank account that is linked with his/her stripe account. So i then try to charge the user

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(CLIENT_SECRET);

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => 1000*100,
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    'source' => $resp['access_token'],
    'destination' => $resp['stripe_user_id']
));
```

This gives me an error

```
No such token: sk_test_HSBM8.....
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong as this is the first time i am working with Stripe Connect

Comment: have you set Stripe.setPublishableKey ?

Comment: @KamleshGupta why do I need to set `Stripe.setPublishableKey` for Stripe connect? if does not seem to mentioned this in their documentation https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts

Comment: why you can not pass directly access tocken like  $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    // Stripe_Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_WcXfM3Tsb0IlkSKmbZTYnq5d");
    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(
      array(
        "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "testm@example.com",
        "application_fee" => 5 // amount in cents
      ),
       ACCESS_TOKEN
    );

Comment: There is no form that gets submitted so there is no `$_POST['stripeToken']`, since user is connected via oauth so the charge is automatically being deducted.